# How to deal with events in nodejs/node-red

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous, node-red

I work with node-red and develop a custom node at the moment that uses [websockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws) to connect to a device and request data from it.

```
function query(node, msg, callback) {

    var uri = 'ws://' + node.config.host + ':' + node.config.port;
    var protocol = 'Lux_WS';
    node.ws = new WebSocket(uri, protocol);

    var login = "LOGIN;" + node.config.password;

    node.ws.on('open', function open() {
        node.status({fill:"green",shape:"dot",text:"connected"});
        node.ws.send(login);
        node.ws.send("REFRESH");
    }); 

    node.ws.on('message', function (data, flags) {
        processResponse(data, node);
    }); 

    node.ws.on('close', function(code, reason) {
        node.status({fill:"grey",shape:"dot",text:"disconnected"});
    }); 

    node.ws.on('error', function(error) {
        node.status({fill:"red",shape:"dot",text:"Error " + error});
    }); 

}
```

In the `processResponse` function I need process the first response. It gives me an XML with several ids that I need to request further data.
I plan to set up a structure that holds all the data from the first request, and populate it further with the data that results from the id requests.

And that's where my problem starts, whenever I send a query from within the `processResponse` function, I trigger an event that results in the same function getting called again, but then my structure is empty.

I know that this is due to the async nature of nodejs and the event system, but I simply don't see how to circumvent this behavior or do my code in the right way.

If anybody can recommend examples on how to deal with situations like this or even better could give an example, that would be great!

Comment: Two words, state machine

Comment: @hardillb it would be great if we built up a useful set of answers for Node-RED on StackOverflow as this would make it a lot easier for new users to learn.

Comment: @JulianKnight There is no where near enough information in this question to write a proper answer (and we'd end up basically writing the whole node if there was). The hint to go research state machines looks like it had the desired effect as the OP has not responded. Also this is a generic NodeJS question that just happens to have been tagged Node-RED. There is no benefit to the larger community from this question.

Comment: I agree but it would surely be better to ask for more info. I've noticed that Node-RED questions have very few answers but often lots of comments. It doesn't look good & it makes it hard for people to find definitive answers so my comment was more generic really, sorry for the confusion.